# Bind9 DNS: Make webmail.mydomain.com go to a local IP instead of external IP

Tags: linux, dns, bind

I have a mail server running on a linux server.

Internally, I can access it via https://192.168.0.253/webaccess and externally I can access it via https://webmail.mydomain.com/webaccess

I'd like to be able to access webmail.mydomain.com internally, the problem is that a DNS lookup to this address goes to the public IP of our network and from within, that won't work.

I have bind9 installed on our linux server (internal) and can use that for DNS lookups - that server is my primary DNS address. Could anyone please describe how I can configure bind to resolve webmail.mydomain.com to 192.168.0.253?

Answer (score 1):

Configure Bind to use a different view for the internal users; see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bind9-named-configure-views/

Answer (score -1):

in */etc/hosts* (or equivalent for the OS) on the client you can set webmail.mydomain.com to *192.168.0.253*, as the hosts file is checked before any DNS servers.